# Detect another application's window is scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, scrollbar, hook

From WPF, is is possible to detect that another application's scrollbar (e.g. Notepad) is being scrolled?

I have looked into this and it seems like maybe I would need to register a global hook in a native DLL from which I could receive messages.  The messages I am interested could be WM_VSCROLL (see [WM_VSCROLL message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

At any rate, I am looking for the simplest implementation.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I think you kinda answered your own question there... I don't see any simpler way than hooking to the Windows API DLL's. It could only be simpler if you were the one making the other application.

Comment: UI Automation should be able to handle this.